# Latest IOS10 Autoplay Enable

Tags: html, ios10, autoplay

Anyone does have the idea of how apply the html5 code for video and allow autoplay in Ios10 or latest? Cause seems like Ios10 do have the latest update and it couldn't allow Autoplay. Following are the tag that im using.

```
<video preload="auto" id="lady_vid">
  <source src="vid/lady.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to enable autoplay by using the following code:

```
<video autoplay muted playsinline>
    <source src="http://example.com/video.mp4">
</video>
```

You need `autoplay` to enable autoplay.
You need `muted`, because only videos without audio track or with disabled audio track can be autoplayed.
You need `playsinline`, because only inlined videos can be autoplayed. This will also cause your video to be displayed inside the page itself and not be opened in fullscreen video view.

I was only able to enable it after specifying full url to the video, e.g. `http://example.com/video.mp4` (this is a fake url obviously). It was not working with relative url, such as

```
<source src="video.mp4">
```

or

```
<source src="folder/video.mp4">
```

===========

**Update:**

After testing video on iOS10 for a while, I've realized that iOS10 fails to play a lot of videos. It's not a codec problem: if you encode two videos with exactly the same parameters, one might play and the other one won't.

What's even more intresting, is that most videos that cannot be played on iOS10 play perfectly well on iOS9 and iOS8.

So if your video isn't playing, try opening it with iOS Safari browser via direct link - maybe it doesn't work at all on iOS10.

Comment: Did you find a way to turn the audio on?

Comment: @socca1157 Yes, you can turn audio on as usual with javascript, but you need to run this code from click event: videoView.muted = false; videoView.volume = 1.0; Usually that means that you'll have to display "mute" button somewhere on top of your video and enable sound only when the user presses that button.